# Import Excel into mySQL taking too long

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

So, I have a form that allows users to upload an excel sheet and then the system will import that excel data into mySQL.

However, every time I submit the form using AJAX, it starts the process, saves about half of the data, and then gives me a 504 gateway error. I have already changed the PHP config timeout to 300 but it still gives in half way through. I do not think that an excel sheet with a little under 1000 rows should be taking 5+ minutes?

Here is my code:

```
 public function postImportGroup(Request $request)
{

    if($request->hasFile('import_numbers')) {
       $file = $request->file('import_numbers');
       $file_extension = Input::file('import_numbers')->getClientOriginalExtension();
       $supportedExt = array('csv', 'xls', 'xlsx');

    if (!in_array_r($file_extension, $supportedExt)) {
        return response()->json([
            'status' => 'error',
            'msg' => 'Please make sure that the uploaded file is a valid CSV, XLS, XLSX sheet.',
        ]);
    }

   }

    $results = Excel::load($file)->get();

    $results = json_decode($results[0], true);

    $class = new DailyGroup();
    $class->title = $request->group_name;
    $class->user_id = Auth::guard('client')->user()->id;
    $class->entries = count($results);
    $class->save();

    foreach ($results as $r => $value) {
      //$data = array_values($value);
        //return $value["employee_number"];
      $group = new DailyGroupLocations();

      $address = $value["address"] . ',' . $value["city"] . ',' . $value["state"] . ',' . $value["zip"];
      $c = $value["country"];

      $file_contents = file_get_contents('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=' . urlencode($address) . '&components=country:' . urlencode($c) .'&sensor=false&key=xxx');
      $json_decode = json_decode($file_contents);


      if (isset($json_decode->results[0])) {  
        $group->lat = $json_decode->results[0]->geometry->location->lat;
        $group->lng = $json_decode->results[0]->geometry->location->lng;
    }
      $phone = preg_replace('/\D+/', '', $value["ph"]);
      $phone = '1'.$phone;

      $group->user_id = Auth::guard('client')->user()->id;
      $group->group_id = $class->id;
      $group->employee_number = $value["employee_number"];
      $group->work_date = $value["work_date"]["date"];
      $group->first_name = $value["name"];
      $group->last_name = $value["lastname"];
      $group->phone = $phone;
      $group->email = $value["email"];
      $group->job_number = $value["job_number"];
      $group->address = $value["address"];
      $group->city = $value["city"];
      $group->state = $value["state"];
      $group->zip = $value["zip"];
      $group->country = $value["country"];
      $group->job_name = $value["job_name"];
      $group->location = $value["location"];
      $group->shift_description = $value["shift_description"];
      $group->shift_start = $value["shift_start_time"];
      $group->shift_end = $value["shift_end_time"];
      $group->post_hours = $value["post_hours"];
      $group->save();
}

        return response()->json([
            'status' => 'success',
            'msg' => 'All data uploaded successfully. Please wait for tables to refresh.',
            //'url' => '/user/location/location-areas'
        ]);
}
```

Is there anything I can do to optimize this? Am I running to many things in the foreach statement? Any tips or tricks I can use?

Comment: Where is the slow down? Code doesn't tell us much about database layer or how save() operates. Is it the geocoding calls to Google? 1000 rows, 1 second per request to google... adds up. Id run this as a job and not keep the user/client on the hook for the whole process.

Comment: Do you think it could be the calls to Google? I will disable the calls and test to see if it becomes faster.

Comment: @ficuscr okay so it is definitely the google calls. Just checked it. In terms of running it as a job, would I go through it by calling it every minute or every 10 minutes? Would you be able to guide me in the right direction?

Comment: There are many approaches to a job queue. RabbitMQ to cron firing off a script every so often. Yes, a simple approach would be fire a script off every 10 minutes, look for things to process. Add some logging in for user to have feedback. etc If you don't need super precise lat/lng data then base it off their zip code. Google keeps increasing rates anyway :)

Comment: Got it. Thank you for the suggestion going to see how well it will work. @ficuscr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

its Not the excel file taking its time... its the google  geocode call which is blocking your code from executing.

you can get yourself an google api key to speed up your process.

reference: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key

you should also Check for the response status of your geocode calls

```
$status = json_decode->results[0]->status;
```

possible status values:

- OK
- ZERO_RESULTS
- OVER_QUERY_LIMIT
- INVALID_REQUEST
- UNKNOWN_ERROR

if its possible in your case you could consider pre-geocoding your dataset, store the lat and lng values with the address so you do Not have to geocode on the fly if you expect or need a fast execution.

Comment: [FYI](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/usage-and-billing): "All Google Maps Platform API requests must include an API key; we no longer support keyless access."

Comment: @ficuscr This statement from google was not for geocoding.

Comment: Link to source is in comment on FYI text: here, https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/usage-and-billing your link is out dated. Billing must now be enabled and API key in use.

Comment: I already have an API key. Just didn't include it in the code. Where can I go to speed up amount of requests per second? @netzding

Comment: That is a red herring. You are not doing more than 50 requests a second. Don't worry about it.

Comment: @ficuscr thank you. I think I am just going to run a job in the background and just notify the user when all the coordinates are created.

Comment: oh well... got the proof on our live servers but yeah you are definetly right, from „now“ on no application should skip on the api key - thanks for your reminder

Comment: @ficuscr you were totally right... until today everything worked on live... but now im in a hurry applying the auth keys!

Comment: That was me a few days ago :) Be sure to set daily quotas to avoid surprises.